# Joint PDF of Solid Triangle,$ x+y\leq 1$ find $Px,y(x|y)$ for solid triangle?

Tags: probability, statistics

$x+y\leq 1$
find $Px,y(x|y)$ for solid triangle?

Comment: plz answer me as soon as possible,i would be grateful to you. Thanks....

Comment: It is best not to ask for speed in answering.

Comment: As you can tell from the answer given, it is difficult to guess what you are asking, could you please **edit** your question to state clearly what you want to know, what the **definitions** are and what you have **tried** so far.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you want the conditional density of $X$, given that $Y=y$. We can proceed from fundamental principles, or from the formula that was undoubtedly supplied to you. This formula looks like
$$f_X(x|Y=y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}.$$

The joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is $2$ inside the triangle bounded by the axes and the line $x+y=0$, and $0$ elsewhere.

For $f_Y(y)$, we "integrate out" $x$ in the joint density function. For $0\lt y\lt 1$, we have
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{x=0}^{1-y} 2\,dx=2(1-y).$$

Now you have the ingredients needed to write down the conditional density function.